# In perl, I am trying to print the ENV variables and their values in 2 different columns but its not working

Tags: perl

```
my $longest=0;

foreach my $key ( keys %ENV ) {
my $key_length = length( $key );
$longest = $key_length if $key_length > $longest;
}
foreach my $key ( sort keys %ENV ) {
printf "%-${longest}s %s\n", $key, $ENV{$key};
```

This does print the ENV variable name and value in two separate columns ; 
But the ENV values that are long, wrap around :(

Any pointers on how I can ensure that the second column doesn't wrap around to first columns space ?

Output I am getting

```
xyz  123
abc  456,
789
```

Desired output

```
xyz  123
abc  456,
     789
```

Comment: You'll need to insert the line break + indent where you want it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Text::Wrap qw( wrap );

# local $Text::Wrap::columns = ...;  # Default = 76

my $indent = " " x ($longest + 1);

for my $key ( sort keys %ENV ) {
   printf("%-${longest}s %s\n", $key, wrap("", $indent, $ENV{$key}));
}
```

Alternatively, one could probably use [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6::Form) (a Perl5 module that provides Perl6-style forms).